# Cannot save transient entity. NHibernate

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

**Mappings**

```
<class name="Project" optimistic-lock="version">
    <id name="Id" column="ProjectID" type="guid" unsaved-value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">  
        <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>
    <version name="Version" generated="always" type="Int32" unsaved-value="0">
       <column name="Version" sql-type="int" not-null="true" />
    </version>
    <!-- properties -->
</class>
```

When debugging it is plain to see that `Version equals 0`.

```
public class Project {
    public virtual Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual Int32 Version { get; set; }
}
```

But when saving exception occurs:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Version', table 'XXXX.dbo.Project'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `generated="always"` with a type `Int32`.

> generated (optional - defaults to never): Specifies that this version
>   property value is actually generated by the database.

You can find more info [here](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-version) and [here](http://ayende.com/blog/3946/nhibernate-mapping-concurrency).

You can change your type to `Timestamp` or remove the attribute.

I would suggest to change your `Version` property this way:

```
public virtual int Version { get; private set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

`generated="always"` means the DB, not NHibernate, will generate this value, and NH will retrieve it afterwards.

If this is not the case, remove that attribute. In fact, you can remove all the attributes except `name`, because you're setting them to default values.